# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
import os
from Ultimatix_login import ultimatix_login1
from searchtest import searchtest

dir=os.getcwd()
search_tests=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ultimatix_login1)
search_tests2=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(searchtest)

main_test=unittest.TestSuite([search_tests,search_tests2])
outfile=open(dir+"\Main_runresult.html","w")
runner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,report_title="Test_Report",descriptions="main_Test")
runner.run(main_test)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(main_test)
```

After running this code I'm getting the above-mentioned error please help me out this. I have tried so many things but I failed.

I am getting error as below:

> runner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,report_title="Test_Report",descriptions="main_Test")
>   TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'

Comment: What exactly is HtmlTestRunner…?

Comment: it used to print the test results in html file.

Comment: I guessed as much, but we need to know **what code exactly** you're including there.

Comment: code is abstracted and im running the main class with **HTML-runner** to get the **test reports** in a html format.

Comment: Is it possible you are using this? -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-testRunner/1.0.3...

Comment: yeah im using the same one

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty obvious, HTMLTestRunner has a mandatory argument "output" which is the output directory.
As you can see here: https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner
you have to instantiate it as:

```
HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='example_dir')
```

Comment: after changing it my test is running and html is generated but its not showing any results except an empty page